# convert a string to a list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, dataframe

I saved in a dataframe a list of arrays; I saved the dataframe in a csv file but when i load the dataframe from the csv file the list is converted to a string as follow :

'[array([-0.21776447,  1.94662631, -0.02061403, -1.06242895,  0.51580483,
0.84616739, -0.35470748,  0.71752894, -0.64087838, -0.90477067,
-0.87875217,  1.18960667, -0.50612909,  0.4665195 ,  1.24713123,
-1.36049497, -2.12931776, -0.55776656, -0.23218341,  1.04019845,
-0.12026928, -0.82667983,  1.40401661,  1.27230537,  0.91537869,
0.36053681,  1.29024398,  0.52343184, -0.00590229, -0.98300529,
-0.13295007, -1.4403007 , -0.35281342,  0.26705894, -0.97358376,
0.06068619, -1.08775687, -0.29690626, -1.79121327, -1.51950073,
-0.16505909,  1.41769159,  0.07625853, -1.6438874 ,  1.09479594,
-1.85290635, -1.66944003, -0.45439029, -0.8185733 ,  0.37505013,
2.61907673,  0.74952161,  0.3836253 ,  0.73246962, -0.56043512,
1.41767979, -0.31556323, -0.6996119 ,  2.15180445,  2.24129105,
1.22645879,  0.63539791, -1.37317276, -0.58658475,  1.01938224,
-0.5643574 , -0.43764979,  0.84042221, -0.02521055, -0.25739807,
-0.75666386, -0.30023479, -0.13447203, -0.35176593, -2.21974754,
-0.05423702,  0.59461212, -0.03212894,  0.80454552,  0.71565092,
-0.03145088, -1.18737686, -0.45311856, -0.2682128 ,  0.57243162,
-0.43173409, -0.5979476 , -0.56365067,  2.45257425, -0.69499886,
1.67338216,  0.6577723 , -2.20462728,  1.89439213, -0.77868176,
1.27529454,  1.13561511, -0.32959926,  0.54175907,  1.49100828,
0.7971406 ,  1.62917829, -0.50094146, -1.52248728,  1.82014203,
-1.52471185, -1.07085752, -0.03872956, -0.33147889, -1.39245462,
-1.17561519,  1.04106796,  0.91994339, -1.31613708, -0.86605591,
-0.35242975,  0.46665138, -0.39142504, -0.06905203,  0.23615381,
0.4982726 ,  1.58158457,  0.04116941, -2.25005054, -2.02018046,
-2.34803295, -2.12728405, -0.22773929]), array([ 0.78476542,  0.36510938, -0.22201738,  0.33344054,  0.66002798,
1.04811633, -0.74085087,  0.4717159 , -0.52175593, -1.15061355,
-0.82517505,  0.49312562, -0.71224177, -0.23590763,  0.82889503,
-0.51173097, -2.59179926,  0.13323589, -0.50235003,  1.7068584 ,
-0.05444423, -0.55864125,  1.08326852,  0.09762229,  1.55480027,
1.17310476,  2.00861526,  0.97825867,  0.36275756, -0.98986304,
-0.53150511, -0.85455537, -0.12432148,  0.53677124, -1.02391899,
0.20761853, -1.56118715, -0.4576185 , -1.46698618, -0.00973426,
-0.85559165, -0.01452565, -1.28508437, -2.24180269,  1.23775017,
-1.54183257, -2.28182721, -0.77985907, -0.73780286,  1.16324282,
1.15814352,  0.50346649,  0.90335023,  0.05898738, -0.7881183 ,
0.28184012, -0.66022235, -0.71335942,  0.29894882,  1.58489764,
0.76380503,  1.03203022, -1.11737084, -2.08161926, -0.56036514,
-1.17878103,  0.21545932,  0.08810213, -1.27903306, -0.02291848,
-1.49333811,  0.64720154, -0.11084566,  0.87249887, -1.44524634,
-0.49819827,  0.88292462,  0.19688626,  1.04408574, -1.08764827,
-1.56752992, -1.92506552, -0.34900814,  0.31278601,  0.32213116,
-0.78489846, -0.16117564,  0.29856566,  1.51471353, -0.16663966,
1.92870605, -0.13353279, -1.70929968,  1.99274492, -0.20634574,
0.89439702,  0.01207307,  1.14236736,  1.77986193,  1.08513868,
1.29714954,  1.8898114 ,  0.05249014, -1.3841002 ,  2.29394174,
-0.77281928, -0.51812041, -1.4319005 ,  0.96838081, -0.47521651,
0.20880216,  0.67759538,  1.33403838, -1.2016139 , -0.70688462,
-0.35534123, -0.40961772,  0.23230565,  0.6360088 ,  1.34696698,
0.5512833 ,  1.271474  ,  0.87532711, -1.22916806, -1.14466679,
-2.74599314, -1.514256  , -0.0598809 ])]'

So, how to convert this string the original list of arrays using python ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you _certain_ it's a string? what does calling `type()` on it show?

Comment: It returns      ( str )

Comment: How are you reading the CSV? What do you see in the file if you open it in application, e.g. Excel, Notepad.

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('filex.csv', lineterminator='\n')

Comment: I think your need your string list to look like this. not witht the array thingy. ```x = '[([-0.21776447, 1.94662631,1.514256 , -0.0598809 ])]'``` Then ast works fine

Comment: no I want it as it is, without the  '  '  ... as a list of arrays

Comment: Fields in a CSV file are just strings, it doesn't support types like numpy arrays or pandas series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something as shown below.

```
import ast
x='[array([-0.21776447, 1.94662631,1.514256 , -0.0598809 ]),array([-0.21776447, 1.94662631,1.514256 , -0.0598809 ])]'
x = x.replace('array', '')
x =ast.literal_eval(x)
```

output

```
[[-0.21776447, 1.94662631, 1.514256, -0.0598809], [-0.21776447, 1.94662631, 1.514256, -0.0598809]]
```

ast did not like the 'array' so I removed it.

Comment: There is many arrays in the list, in the example I gave only two arrays

Comment: So like ```'[[array([-0.21776447, 1.94662631,1.514256 , -0.0598809 ])],[array([-0.21776447, 1.94662631,1.514256 , -0.0598809 ])]]'``` just many more times?

Comment: yes kind a [array([-0.21776447, 1.94662631,1.514256 , -0.0598809 ])],array([-0.21776447, 1.94662631,1.514256 , -0.0598809 ]),....]

Comment: It works the same. Just take out the slicing [0]. LOok at my edit